# Azure Stream Analytics : Select data with the last timestamp only

Tags: sql, azure, dataset, streaming, dashboard

I'm working on a way to stream status of some jobs that are running on an HPC resource (sort of like trying to create a dashboard to look at real time flight status). I generate and push data every 60 seconds. Unfortunately, this way i end up with a lot of repeated data as the status of each 'job' changes unpredictably. I need a way to only keep the latest data. I'm not an SQL pro and do this work in my free time so any help will be appreciated!

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    Job, Ref, Location, Queue, Description, Status, ElapTime, cast (Time as datetime) as Time
INTO
    output_source
FROM
    input_source
```

Here is what my output looks like when i test the query:

[Query Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxXtK.png)

As you can see, in the image, there are two sets of data with two different time stamps. I would like the query to return all the columns associated with only the last timestamp. How do i do this? Any ideas? Apologies if this is a repeated question. I have not found an answer that has helped me solve this problem.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: *I [...] do this work in my free time* - so do a lot of people answering questions ;-)

Comment: You basically want to keep only the last row per unique timestamp and discard all others or do you want some aggregation grouped by time?

Comment: I would like to keep all the rows that have the latest timestamp. So, from the attached image, i'd like the output to be the set of rows associated to the first (upper) green box of identical timestamps. Is that clearer? Thanks!

Comment: what's the data type of your Time column?

Comment: I try and cast it into a datetime format in the query. I send out JSON data from my data generation/transmission scripts without any type definition so i guess it comes to the asa input stream as a string.